# How to change antd table selected row background color

Tags: reactjs, html-table, antd

I am using antd table with checkbox in my react application

I want to change the background of selected table

```
const columns = [
    {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
    },
    {
        title: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
    },
    {
        title: 'Address',
        dataIndex: 'address',
    },
];
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
    data.push({
        key: i,
        name: `Edward King ${i}`,
        age: 32,
        address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`,
    });
}
```

I used rowClassName to change the background color when selected but it is not working

```
const TestTable = () => {
    const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const start = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        // ajax request after empty completing
        setTimeout(() => {
            setSelectedRowKeys([]);
            setLoading(false);
        }, 1000);
    };
    const onSelectChange = (newSelectedRowKeys) => {
        console.log('selectedRowKeys changed: ', newSelectedRowKeys);
        setSelectedRowKeys(newSelectedRowKeys);
    };
    const rowSelection = {
        selectedRowKeys,
        onChange: onSelectChange,
    };


    const rowClassName = (record) => {
        console.log("key is ", record)
        return record.key === selectedRowKey ? 'selected-row' : '';
    };


    const hasSelected = selectedRowKeys.length > 0;
    return (
        <div>
            <div
                style={{
                    marginBottom: 16,
                }}
            >
                <Button type="primary" onClick={start} loading={loading}>
                    Reload
                </Button>
                <span
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: 8,
                    }}
                >
                    {hasSelected ? `Selected ${selectedRowKeys.length} items` : ''}
                </span>
            </div>
            <Table rowClassName="now" className='time-table-row-select' rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestTable
```

css

```
.selected-row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const TestTable = () => {
    const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const start = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        // ajax request after empty completing
        setTimeout(() => {
            setSelectedRowKeys([]);
            setLoading(false);
        }, 1000);
    };
    const onSelectChange = (newSelectedRowKeys) => {
        console.log('selectedRowKeys changed: ', newSelectedRowKeys);
        setSelectedRowKeys(newSelectedRowKeys);
    };
    const rowSelection = {
        selectedRowKeys,
        onChange: onSelectChange,
    };


    const rowClassName = (record) => {
        console.log("key is ", record)
        return selectedRowKeys.some(key => key === record.key) ? 'selected-row' : '';
    };


    const hasSelected = selectedRowKeys.length > 0;
    return (
        <div>
            <div
                style={{
                    marginBottom: 16,
                }}
            >
                <Button type="primary" onClick={start} loading={loading}>
                    Reload
                </Button>
                <span
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: 8,
                    }}
                >
                    {hasSelected ? `Selected ${selectedRowKeys.length} items` : ''}
                </span>
            </div>
            <Table rowClassName={(record) => rowClassName(record)} className='time-table-row-select' rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestTable
```

Your code should be like this.

I fixed this function:

```
const rowClassName = (record) => {
        console.log("key is ", record)
        return record.key === selectedRowKey ? 'selected-row' : '';
    };
```

to be:

```
const rowClassName = (record) => {
            console.log("key is ", record)
            return selectedRowKeys.some(key => key === record.key) ? 'selected-row' : '';
        };
```

because `selectedRowKeys` is an array of strings and it cannot be equal to a basic string.